# Ampersand's booleanClass to toggle, add/remove a property

Tags: css, ampersand, ampersand.js

I found this documentation but I still couldn't figure out how I will use it in a code. https://ampersandjs.com/docs/#ampersand-dom-bindings-booleanclass

What I want to do is use Ampersand's binding rather than using Jquery $() to capture or fire an event when I click an element. Can someone please show an example of an ampersand code that will toggle, add/remove class that I can use with css. This will be helpful in for example expanding or collapsing an html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing two things here: `events` and `bindings`. `Bindings` are binding specific variables (defined in `props` or `session`), while `events` are triggering events, like jquery does. Here is an example of using these two together:

```
module.exports = AmpersandView.extend({
    template: yourTemplate,
    props: {
        switchedOn: ['boolean', true, false]
    },

    bindings: {
        'switchedOn': {
            type: 'booleanClass',
            name: 'active',
            selector: '#your-selector'
        }
    },
    events: {
        'click #your-selector': function(e){
            this.switchedOn = !this.switchedOn;
            var el = e.target;//this is the element which triggered the event. In jquery it would be 'this' inside of the handler
        }
    }
})
```

Here I define the variable `switchedOn` to which the state of class `active` of `#your-selector` is bound.

Personally, I think it's a bit too much if you need just to toggle an element. In many cases jquery will require less code.

Comment: WOW! Your explanation is better than their docs. Thank you so much!

Comment: We're trying our best to make sure we're not importing jquery and not relying on it. I have another question - What if my elements are `<li class="items">`, do I change selector to class like `selector: '.items'` then `'click .items': function(){`? But how will it know which I clicked since there are multiple `<li>` most of the time?

Comment: @devwannabe, in the example above you can do like this, for example: `'click .items': function(e){ e.target.getAttribute('data-action')}`. Basically, in `e.target` you have the element that triggered the event. And then you can do whatever you want with it. In my example, I get the value of a `data-action` attribute. I'll edit my answer. By the way, if my answer answers your initial question (and works for you), be sure to accept it ;)